# Deep learning: parameter selection and result interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a multiclass(7 labels) classification problem implemented in MLP. I am trying to classify 7 cancers based on some data. The overall accuracy is quite low, around 58%. However, some of the cancers is classified with accuracy around 90% for different parameters. Below cancer 1,2,3 etc means different types of cancer, For example 1= breast cancer, 2 = lung cancer etc. Now, for different parameter settings I get different classification accuracy. For example,

## 1. hyper parameters

```
    learning_rate = 0.001
    training_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 100
    hidden_size = 256
    #overall accuracy 53%, cancer 2 accuracy 91%, cancer 5 accuracy 88%, 
     #cancer 6 accuracy 89%
```

## 2. hyper parameters

```
    learning_rate = 0.01
    training_epochs = 30
    batch_size = 100
    hidden_size = 128
    #overall accuracy 56%, cancer 2 accuracy 86%, cancer 5 accuracy 93%, 
    #caner 6 accuracy 75%
```

As you can see, for different parameter settings I am getting totally different results. Cancer 1,3,4,7 have very low accuracy, so I excluded them. But cancer 2, 5,6 have comparatively better results. But, for cancer 6, the results vary by great number depending on the parameter settings.

An important note is, here overall accuracy is not important but if I can classify 2-3 cancers with more than 90% accuracy that is more important. So my question is, how do I interpret the results? In my paper how should I show the results? which parameter settings should I show/use? Or should I show different parameter settings for different cancer types? So basically, how to handle this type of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data Imbalance?

The first question you'll have to ask yourself is, do you have a balanced dataset, or do you have data imbalance? With this I mean, how many instances of each class do you have in your training and test datasets?

Suppose, for example, suppose that 90% of all the instances in your dataset are cancer 2, and the remaining 10% is spread out over the other classes. Then, you can very easily get 90% accuracy by implementing a very dumb classifier that simply classifies everything as cancer 2. This is probably not what you want out of your classifier though.

#### Interpretation of Results

I'd recommend reporting [confusion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) instead of just raw accuracy numbers. This will provide some information about which classes get confused for which other classes by the classifier, which may be interesting (e.g. different types of cancer may be similar to some extent if they often get confused for each other). Especially if you have data imbalance, I'd also recommend reporting other metrics such as Precision and/or Recall, instead of Accuracy.

#### Which parameter settings to use/show?

This depends on what problem you're really trying to solve. Is correct detection of every class equally important? If so, overall accuracy is probably the most important metric. Are certain classes more important to accurately detect than others? In this case you may want to look into "cost-sensitive classification", where different classification mistakes have different costs. If you simply don't know (don't have this domain knowledge), I'd recommend reporting as many different settings and metrics as you realistically can.

Comment: Thanks for nice reply. It was really helpful specially for the idea that some cancer may get confused with other cancer. BTW, not all class data same, they vary by 5-10%, hope this is not a big deal.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk Nope, small differences like that are inevitable. Class imbalance becomes a more serious issue if it's more extreme (e.g. 90% to 10%, or 99% to 1%)